# Publicly Accessible TSPLib95 Solutions

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, soft-question

I have asked [this question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2602183/where-are-the-optimal-tours-of-tsplib-95-instances), but besides earning a TumbleWeed award, there was no feedback.

My question is, where I can download *all* optimal tours of the TSPLib95 library? I already did a lot of googling and found that the original resource of the [University of Heidelberg](https://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/TSPLIB95/) hasn't been upated since 2008 and has not all optimal tours available.  Also the distance calculations of the X-ray problems are hard to understand/find online.

I would be a bit surprised if *the* standard collection of TSP problems were not maintained and available anymore; I am currently checking new heuristics for the TSP problem and would like to be able to provide results that are based on a collection of standard instances.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.